# Generating function to calculate number of ways of distributing $10$ or less items to $3$ people.

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

> There is a container of 10 identical chocolate frogs and three students, Adam, Bob,
>   and Charles, are to be given some of these chocolate frogs, but not necessarily all of the chocolate frogs.
>   In how many ways can the chocolate frogs be given to the students if each student must
>   receive at least one chocolate frog each?

First we note that this is equivalent to
$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=10$

$x_1,x_2,x_3\geq1,x_4\geq0$

Using a genearting function this is

$(t^1+\dots+t^{8})(t^1+\dots+t^{8})(t^1+\dots+t^{8})(1+t^1+\dots+t^{7})$

Coefficient of $10$

E.g.

$\text{Coefficient}\left[\left(\sum _{i=1}^8 t^i\right) \left(\sum _{i=1}^8 t^i\right) \left(\sum _{i=1}^8 t^i\right) \sum _{i=0}^7 t^i,t,10\right]=120$

Is this the correct method?

---

By stars and bars
$y_1=x_1-1\geq0$

$y_1+1 = x_1$ same procedure with $y_2,y_3$, and obtain $y_1+y_2+y_3+x_4=7$, this is the same as 7 stars and $3$ bars, we have ${{7+3-1} \choose {7}}=36$

Comment: It is $120$. The number is easier to find using Stars and Bars.

Comment: @AndréNicolas E.g. convert to $y_1=x_1-1$ etc, so $y_1+y_2+y_3+x_4=13$ and then you have 13 stars, and three bars. Take ${{13+3-1} \choose {13}}=105$ I can see that ${{16} \choose {14}}=120$, but I can't see where I lost a star?

Comment: We want to solve $y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4=11$, $y_i\ge 1$. The number of solutions is $\binom{11-1}{4-1}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ah, I see, stars and bars wants all to be $y_i \geq 1$, not $y_i \geq 0$

Comment: @AndréNicolas I think it was my mistake, I believe you were right with $=7$ since $z_1=x_1-1\Rightarrow z_1+1=x_1$. But it still doesn't seem to work in this form

Comment: That's a relief, anyway I still prefer to make everything $\ge 1$. By the way, interpretation of "some" is not obvious, it could mean $\ge 0$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas To clarify: When you have $x_i \geq 1$ you take ${n-1} \choose {r-1}$, but when you have $x_i \geq 0$ you take ${n+r-1} \choose n$, where $r$ is number of variables. That is why my method didn't work. I should have had ${{7+4-1} \choose {7}}=120$. I was reducing $r$ by one without thinking about it.

Comment: That's right, for $\ge 1$ we choose $n-1$  gaps to put separators into. For $\ge 0$ we use $\binom{n+r-1}{n}$, though I often think of it as $\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$, the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is correct. But stars and bars would be easier as Andre Nicolas has suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that neither uses stars and bars nor generating functions.

Distribute one each to A, B, C, and initially assume that the remaining $7$ are distinct.

Then the first of these seven has $4$ places (uparrows) to go, $\uparrow \bullet\uparrow \bullet\uparrow \bullet\uparrow$,

the next will have $5$ places to go, and so on, thus $4\cdot5\cdot6\cdot7\cdot8\cdot9\cdot10$

Finally, divide by $7!$ since they are identical to get $\quad\dfrac{4\cdot5\cdot6\cdot7\cdot8\cdot9\cdot10}{7!} = 120$